# Função que não está sendo executada em C

Tags: c, algoritmo

Este é um código cujo o objetivo é somar todos os números inteiros entre a e b. Sendo "a" menor que "b". A saída esperada era um número representando essa soma, porém, após a leitura de a e b, nada acontece.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int soma(int n1,int n2) 
{
    int i,s; 
    for(i;n2-1;i++) 
        s=s+i; 
    }
    return s; 
}
int main()
{
    int a,b,s; 
    printf("Digite dois numeros:");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    s=soma(a,b);
    printf("Soma=%d",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual o valor inicial da variável i em seu comando for? Não seria: for (i=n1; i<=n2; i++)? Além disso a variável s deve ser inicializada com zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não deu um critério específico claro de onde começa e onde termina, mas o erro pode ser no máximo de um. Este código seu não faz sentido. Ele não tem o bloco de inicialização correto e deveria começar a variável por algum valor, de preferência por onde vai começar a sequência e deve ter uma condição de término do laço, então deve haver uma comparação se a variável já chegou onde precisa, ou seja, até o número do fim da sequência.

Além disto faltou inicializar a soma então ele pode começar por uma valor aleatório qualquer que estiver na memória o que dará um resultado equivocado.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int soma(int n1, int n2) {
    int soma = 0;
    for (int i = n1; i < n2; i++) soma += i; 
    return soma; 
}
int main() {
    int a, b; 
    printf("Digite dois numeros:");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("\nSoma = %d", soma(a, b));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eNU3za). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ForInit). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ForInit.c).